# Forking and ordering tests in Sbt 0.13.x

Tags: scala, migration, sbt

Here is how it was configured for Sbt 0.12.x:

```
parallelExecution in test := false

testGrouping in Test <<= definedTests in Test map { tests =>
  tests.map { test =>
    import Tests._
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
    new Group(
      name = test.name,
      tests = Seq(test),
      runPolicy = SubProcess(javaOptions = Seq(
        "-server", "-Xms4096m", "-Xms4096m", "-XX:NewSize=3584m", 
        "-Xss256k", "-XX:+UseG1GC", "-XX:+TieredCompilation",
        "-XX:+UseNUMA", "-XX:+UseCondCardMark", 
        "-XX:-UseBiasedLocking", "-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch") ++
        System.getProperties.toMap.map {
          case (k, v)  => "-D" + k + "=" + v
        }))
  }.sortWith(_.name < _.name)
}
```

During migration to Sbt 0.13.x I get the following error:

```
[error] Could not accept connection from test agent: class java.net.SocketException: socket closed
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
    at sbt.ForkTests$$anonfun$mainTestTask$1$Acceptor$2$.run(ForkTests.scala:48)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Migration changes are just [updates in sbt & plugin versions](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/commit/cd952a70fa8728549cd8d8c23ed477f1e68280cb).

Are there any other approaches to forking and ordering of tests in Sbt 0.13.x to overcome that exception?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine on Linux and Mac OS.

Got error on Windows because of limit of classpath length that prevents launching of test agent instance with following error in System.err:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class sbt.ForkMain
```

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error when moving to Scala repo to sbt version sbt.version = 1.3.8 (previously 1.2.8 was ok).  Strangely worked fine on my mac, but failed on teamcity linux build agents.

Fix for me was to set

```
  fork := false,
```

in build.sbt.

Not sure why repo had it previously set to fork := true (guess it was cut/paste from somewhere else as no strong reason for this in this repo), but this change resolved the issue.  Locally on my mac also runs a few seconds faster now.

See here for background
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Forking.html